# Problems importing reference from BibTex

Tags: bibtex

I am using MacOSX Sierra and trying to import my references from a `.bib` file created using `bibdesk` and when I compile the file it doesn't show the bibliography even though I am using `\cite{}` with the correct label of the article.

I run the `.tex` file with the `.bib` file on linux and it works correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Tesis.bib}

\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file looks like this:

```
@article{Yang,
Author = {Jaewong Yang and Jure Leskovec},
Date-Added = {2016-10-05 01:09:03 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-10-05 01:11:20 +0000},
Journal = {Proceedings MDS},
Title = {Definin and evaluating network communities based on ground-truth}}

@book{Watts,
Date-Added = {2016-10-05 01:08:22 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-10-05 01:09:00 +0000},
Publisher = {Princenton University Press},
Title = {Small world},
Year = {1999}}
```

I don't use the `natbib` package. But when I try with this package, it doesn't work. Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you sure the `.bib` file is loaded in the `.tex` file (e.g., via `\bibliography{<bibfile>}` for BibTeX or `\addbibresource{<bibfile>.bib}` for `biblatex`)? Are you sure the file is being found (say, by checking the log files)? If in doubt, please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) that others can see and test.

Comment: Welcome! Have you compiled, then run `bibtex` or `biber` as applicable, then compiled twice more? Can you provide a minimal example we can use to reproduce the problem? What does the console output say? What does the log say?

Comment: I tryed to compile the `.bib` file and I get this error `I couldn't open file name 'Tesis.aux'` I will make a reproducible example. Thanks!

Comment: Note: you do not 'compile' the `.bib` file! It is: `latex myfile.tex`, `bibtex myfile.aux`, `latex myfile.tex`, `latex myfile.tex`. (In fact, the file extensions are optional.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a misunderstanding as to how bibtex works.